# How to import a large SQL query into Visual Studio database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a large file containing 475k rows (around 120Mb) with postalcode data, which i have downloaded from here [postcodedata.nl](http://www.postcodedata.nl/download/).

I have created a table with EntityFramework and adjusted the SQL query so i would be able to use it in Visual Studio.

When i try to run the query it would run for a short while and output:

> Query completed with errors.

while there are no changes made to the database.

I have tested the same query but with 200 rows and 10k rows and it works fine so i suspect the error message is because Visual Studio doesn't have enough memory to proces it.

I have tried to use SQL Server Management Studio but when i run the code there i get the following error:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

I have also tried to use the SQLCMD command as suggested on other Questions but using that throws the following error:

> Msg 701, Level 17, State 123, Server DESKTOP-PUMBLDD\LOCALDB#EE17CAEE, Line 5341
>   There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.

I don't understand why this query won't run in Visual Studio since i could run it in PhpMyAdmin and it worked just fine.

So my question is how can i import these data into my database?

Comment: with bulk load. forget about ef. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, your file has CSV format. There are many options to import CSV to MS SQL database.

1. SQL Server Management Studio: select a database, then Tasks - Import data -> [Flat File Source](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/importing-a-csv-file-into-your-database-with-sql-server-management-studio.aspx)
2. SQL: [BULK INSERT query](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439843/Handling-BULK-Data-insert-from-CSV-to-SQL-Server)
3. C#: SqlBulkCopy class. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), [Direct CSV read](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using.html), [CsvDataReader](http://www.csvreader.com/code/cs/upload_csv.php).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio? Right-click on the database into which you'd like to import the data and select `Tasks > Import Data...`. You can select from multiple options as your data source, including a flat file. The wizard will guide you through the steps.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS does not connect to localdb without using the 'Options' button at the login screen, completing the Connection properties and, in the Additional Connection Properties tab, enter the rest of the VS connection string (DataSource,Attachdbfilename,InitialCatalog etc.)